# A set of axioms for computability

Tags: reference-request, axioms

Is there a paper or text that characterizes the set of computable languages on an alphabet by means of axioms? For instance, such a paper could say that a family of languages is computable if it contains all finite languages, and plus some more axioms. Is there such a paper?

Comment: Maybe useful: Jens Erik Fenstad, [General recursion theory: An axiomatic approach](https://books.google.it/books?id=-89wDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (1980) as well as Y.N.Moschovakis' *Axioms for Computation Theories*, into RO Gandy & CME Yates (editors), [Logic Colloquium '69](https://books.google.it/books?id=W_uEAAAAIAAJ), Elsevier (1971)